# how to handle view child static error in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

this is my code i recently upgraded to angular 8 and this code is no longer working

```
@ViewChild(MatList, { read: ElementRef }) matList: ElementRef;

  // getting a reference to the items/messages within the list
  @ViewChildren(MatListItem, { read: ElementRef }) matListItems: QueryList<MatListItem>;
```

this is message error TS2345: Argument of type '{ read: typeof ElementRef; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; static: boolean; }'.
Property 'static' is missing in type '{ read: typeof ElementRef; }' but required in type '{ read?: any; static: boolean; }'.

Answer (score 4):

After Angular8, **ViewChild static property** is required. So you have to set this in your both ViewChild declarations after the ready property.
So you will have

```
@ViewChild(MatList, {read: ElementRef, static: false}) matList: ElementRef;
@ViewChild(MatListItem, {read: ElementRef, static: false}) matListItems: QueryList<MatListItem>;
```

The **static** property can be set:

- **true** to resolve query results before change detection runs
- **false** to resolve after change detection

Comment: im getting this error now: ERROR iTS2345: Argument of type '{ read: typeof ElementRef; static: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'static' does not exist in type '{ read?: any; }'.

Comment: ok i solved the issue the first view child needed the static false but not the second one. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you need also to add the `static` property, to the object.

set it to false because this is in moste cases the default.

example

```
@ViewChild(MatList, { read: ElementRef, static: false }) matList: ElementRef;
```

Comment: im getting this error now: ERROR iTS2345: Argument of type '{ read: typeof ElementRef; static: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'static' does not exist in type '{ read?: any; }'.

Comment: ok i solved the issue the first view child needed the static false but not the second one. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Angular 8 added a new boolean property for @ViewChild called 'static'.   'static' defines the timing of initialization.  If 'static' is true, initialization will occur on view initialization (ngOnInit). If 'static' is false, initialization will occur after the view is rendered (ngAfterViewInit).

This only applies to @ViewChild, not @ViewChildren, so try this:

```js
@ViewChild(MatList, { static: false, read: ElementRef }) matList: ElementRef;

  // getting a reference to the items/messages within the list   @ViewChildren(MatListItem, { read: ElementRef }) matListItems: QueryList<MatListItem>;
```

Comment: thank you i was having a hard time understanding that